# HttpURLConnection not reading the whole content

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to read a website but strangely it returns only part of it. It just ends in the middle of  section.

I tried using the `setChunkedStreamingMode` method but it didn't change anything.

```
HttpURLConnection connection = ((HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection());
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
// I write some data...
String content = readInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
```

ReadInputStream method:

```
private static String readInputStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {
int len = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
while((len = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    byteArray.write(buffer,0, len);
}
in.close();

return new String(byteArray.toByteArray());
```

}

Is there some sort of limit of data?

Comment: Code seems correct, can you check (by debugging) if the byte array you're passing to the new String(..) actually is truncated or if it has the right length?

Comment: Hm, its 29118 bytes. I'm not sure how to check if its correct... I tried saving the webpage with CTRL+S and its 203kB but I don't know if that's even a correct way to check its size...

Comment: Well, it's quite a different size. I asked because one of the problems could be converting the byte array to a string, if the byte array contains some non-string-representable bytes, like 0.

Comment: Why are you using POST yet comparing to what a browser gets, which is done with GET?

Answer (score 0):

there is no problem with HttpUrlConnection
try this:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
       stringBuilder.append(line);
}
inputStream.close();
```

Comment: It seems to not have blank lines... But its still not the full webpage.